# Error While Deserializing object from Kafka Streams

Tags: java, json, serialization, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

At kafka streams side while writing to Topic, I have serialized Window Key `[test_id@timestamp1/timestamp2]` using `Serdes.String()` serializer from kafka. While retrieving same key from another application I am getting following error while deserialization

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: [B@37e7c0b2; line: 1, column: 1]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:270)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportMappingException(DeserializationContext.java:1234)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1122)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1075)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StringDeserializer.deserialize(StringDeserializer.java:60)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StringDeserializer.deserialize(StringDeserializer.java:11)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3798)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2929)
        at TestAlert$3.extract(TestAlert.java:483)
        at TestAlert$3.extract(TestAlert.java:1)
        at org.apache.ignite.stream.StreamAdapter.addMessage(StreamAdapter.java:181)
        at org.apache.ignite.stream.kafka.KafkaStreamer.access$100(KafkaStreamer.java:47)
        at org.apache.ignite.stream.kafka.KafkaStreamer$1.run(KafkaStreamer.java:156)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Following is the code I have written for serializing Windowed Key. Here `testWinAlerts` is the aggregate result after windowing which has `<Windowd<String>>` as key

```
testWinAlerts.toStream((k,v)->k.toString()).filter((k,v)->{
                return (v!=null);}).to(Serdes.String(),aggrMessageSerde,"Some-Topic");
```

Below is the code at deserializer for converting bytes[] to key in String format again. Where msg.key()[specific to Ignite] provides key in byte format after consumption from topic.

```
String windowKey = objectMapper.readValue(msg.key(), String.class);
```

On further test I have also tried removing `"@",  "/",  "[",  "]"` characters from Window String before writing it to kafka topic, then it worked. But in actual implementation, I dont want to add this extra overhead of removing these characters from String. So how can I remove this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are serializing the input as a **string** with `StringSerde`, but then you are trying to deserialize it with Jackson, which is expecting a **JSON string** as its input. A regular string can be any series of characters. But a JSON string looks like `"string"`—by definition it begins and ends with `"`. So you can't deserialize any string with Jackson, in its serialized state it must begin and end with `"`. Why don't use just use the `StringSerde` to deserialize the key?